# CMake: reuse object files built for a lib into another lib target

Tags: file, object, static, cmake

I'm trying to move my project to CMake, and at the same time have some optimization on the compilation process.

Here's the deal:

- I have several subdirs that are (have to be) each compiled into a static library (this works).
- I want to gather all the object files from each subdir into another bigger, complete, static library.

It looks like this:

```
.
libBig.a  # made from object from subdir1 and subdir2
subdir1/
   src/
   libSubdir1.a
subdir2/
   src/
   libSubdir2.a
```

Today, I managed to use a global variable in which every subdir CMakeLists.txt will append its own source files. I use this variable as a "source" input in my big library:

```
# the big library depends on all the source files
# ${all_src} is automatically filled with each subdir's cpp file
get_property( BigLib_src GLOBAL PROPERTY all_src)
add_library( Big STATIC ${BigLib_src}) # recompiles all the sources
```

Now, this works, not too bad, but the thing is, **all my source files get compiled twice**: once for the subdir library, and once for the big library.

CMake seems to forget that it has already built them.

I *have* to keep the subdir libraries and `ar` can't merge two static libraries.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: What are you moving to CMake from, anyway? Why?

Comment: From handmade Makefiles! I want it to be easy to compile cross-platform, easy to integrate with IDEs, and I thought: why not?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the new OBJECT library feature introduced in [CMake 2.8.8](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/266). The idea is explained [here](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2012-March/003693.html). Basically, the OBJECT library is a similar concept to the [convenience library](http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/autobook/autobook_92.html) known from Autotools to group object files.

Check the complete CMake [OBJECT library tutorial](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/Object-Library).

Comment: I had the same problem and tried the OBJECT Library, it works as a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As of CMake 2.8.8, you can do this using the `OBJECT` library type. See [mloksot's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091583/cmake-reuse-object-files-built-for-a-lib-into-another-lib-target/10635366#10635366) answer. The old situation was that each target had its own directory and CMake would build every dependent object for every target. This guards against a case where one source file could be used multiple times with different `CFLAGS`. (Note that by default CMake is more conservative than automake here: automake will stop reusing object files for different targets only if the targets are built with different `CFLAGS` (and probably `CPPFLAGS`, too).

Comment: That's what I did finally, but I'm still not satisfied with the result, because now my CMakeLists looks bloated and reaches the same number of lines than my original Makefile... maybe for a future release of CMake.

Comment: Have you tried `automake`, with libtool convenience libraries? Or are you sick of twiddling with build systems at this point ;-)? You might not even need the convenience libs if you drive the whole thing from one toplevel nonrecursive `Makefile.am`.